# Subsetting in R (Index Explanation)

Tags: r

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
u <- a > "a"
a[u]
```

**The code gives me the output as:** "b" "c" "d" "e".

What does a[u] mean ? Do vector ***a*** has a new index ***u*** of a vector type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u` is a logical vector which is used to subset `a`.

```
u
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As 1st element is `FALSE`, we select all `TRUE` elements from `a` by doing `a[u]`

```
a[u]
#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

It will be more clear with another example. Consider

```
a <- 11:15
u <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
a[u]
#[1] 12 13 15
```

So all the elements in `a` where `u` is `TRUE` are selected i.e 12, 13 and 15.

Comment: Are we only selecting the elements which are true or we are also storing it somewhere ?

Comment: @Hasnain No, `a` is still the same. Unless you do `b  <- a[u]` then we are storing it in `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure this out yourself by looking at the contents of the `u` vector:

```
u <- a > "a"
u

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

When you then *subset* the vector `a` using this boolean vector `u`, you are telling R to output a vector consisting only of elements for which the input index be `TRUE`.  This leaves you with just:

```
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

To be more explicit:

```
"a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"
 F    T    T    T    T
^^    |______________|
drop    keep the rest
```